# oracle_enhanced_adapter on RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle

RVM version : rvm 1.16.17 (stable)
Rails version : 3.2.9
ruby-oci8 version : 2.1.3
activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter : 1.4.1

They were installed in that order. When I try to scaffold an object with :

```
 rails generate scaffold Product title:string description:text\
 image_url:string price:decimal
```

I get :

```
invoke  active_record
/home/dlsa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': Please install the oracle_enhanced adapter: `gem install activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter` (cannot load such file -- active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_adapter) (LoadError)
    from /home/dlsa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /home/dlsa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
```

... and it goes on and on.

What do you suggest I do. I am a complete ruby/rails newbie.

Answer (score 1):

Would you take a look at [this](https://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced/blob/master/README.md#installation).

Such as:

- `Gemfile` should contain `gem 'activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter', '~> 1.4.0'` entry
- `bundle install`

Hope this helps.